# Task parallel library time slicing

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, task-parallel-library, task, multitasking

I have a used `TaskParallel` library in couple of places in my `WCF` application.
At one place I am using it like:

**Place 1**

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 100 };
Parallel.ForEach(objList, options, recurringOrder =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessSingleRequestForDebitOrder(recurringOrder));
    //var th = new Thread(() => ProcessSingleRequestForDebitOrder(recurringOrder)) { Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal };
    //th.Start();
    //ProcessSingleRequestForDebitOrder( recurringOrder);
});
```

And in of another method I have used it like:

**Place 2**

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessTransaction(objInput.Clone()));
```

Problem is time slicing between the two places. That is if I have called the the method where parallel loop is processing hundreds of records at Place 2 my thread at Place 1 is waiting till all the records have processed. Could some how I can time slice the processing?

I am using task parallel library for .net 3.5 from;

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/

Comment: Not sure why you are starting your tasks in parallel, you are starting threads on multiple threads.

Comment: @BenRobinson Exactly!

Comment: At Place 1 I am starting Task in a Task Parallel Loop and at place 2 I am starting a Thread via using Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: But task parallel loop body is indeed a task, so just starting a new task inside makes no sense.

Comment: Ok.
My thinking is here is a difference between 
ProcessSingleRequestForDebitOrder( recurringOrder); 
or if I write .you can see the commented code.
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessSingleRequestForDebitOrder(recurringOrder));

Comment: Parallel loop will spawn n number of thread where n = my number of cores. So if i will not use Task.Factory.StartNew I will get at the max n parallel threads processing.

Comment: The two concepts just conflict with each other. You either use `Parallel.For/ForEach` and do your work in the body, or use a normal `for/foreach` and start new `Task`s.

Comment: Ok.Let me know what will be the conflicting thing if using both simultaneously. I Will try with Tasks in simple foreach loop as well. But don't know if i can do time slicing/prioritization in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have spawned a lot of tasks in place 1 and place 2 is now queued. The Parallel loop in place 1 does nothing because the body only starts a task which is done very quickly.

Probably, you should remove the StartNew thing from place 1 so that the degree of parallelism is lower. I'm not sure this will completely remove any problems because the Parallel loop might still fully utilize all available pool threads.

Doing IO with Parallel is an anti pattern anyway because the system-chosen DOP almost always is a bad choice. The TPL has no idea how to efficiently schedule IO.

You can make place 2 a `LongRunning` task so that it does not depend on the thread pool and is guaranteed to run.

You also can investigate using async IO so that you do not depend on the thread pool anymore.

Comment: Thanks usr. Also Can I restrict the max number of parallel task can be spawned at place 1. That is When let's say 1000 task is scheduled it will wait the tasks to be free for new processing.
I have tried exactly the same thing as you mentioned about LongRunning at place 2

Comment: PLINQ supports an exact DOP setting. Use PLINQ and determine the optimal DOP experimentally. It is unnecessary and sad that Parallel does not support that.

Comment: What's you mean By IO here. My method simply do some database updates or call with other WCF services e.t.c.

Comment: Ok mean's simple processing. Can you please help me in restricting Tasks at place 1 to not exceed to certain numbers? I am now also checking how can I get advantage of Parallel Linq in my case.
Thanks

Comment: Use PLINQ's WithDegreeOfParallelism method, or the Parallel loop options. Look at the documentation.

Comment: I were using Parallel loop options already. Just edited my question to show how it looks. Now checking https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx